# What type of SMPS is this?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, troubleshooting, education

[image: SMPS for Infinity subwoofer]

What specific type of SMPS is this? I'm working on troubleshooting no power out.

I'm having trouble finding comparable circuits so I can learn how it works. It appears to be some sort of resonant triggered SMPS? I'm way more familiar with the more common IC controlled SMPS with output feedback.

The problem: upon power up, I can hear a faint high frequency switching sound, but nothing on the output side of the transformers. Roughly 160 V on the DC input.

It's from a Infinity powered subwoofer. It was not working when I got it. I have carefully replaced all of the capacitors with high quality low ESR caps from Digikey.

Attached schematic as well as link to service manual PDF. Page 34 is the power supply in working on. The service manual really lacks a lot of critical info like nominal voltages!

[Link to subwoofer service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/701048/Infinity-Prelude-Mts.html)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_converter

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it. So what sets the oscillation frequency? It must just be the transformer core saturation time and natural oscillation frequency of the transformer core?

Comment: It also appears that in this schematic, transformer windings 'A'&'D' are the 'feedback' coils, and windings 'B'&'C' are the 'power' coils doing the heavy current flow. Any idea of how I could find an example application schematic, much like you'd see on an IC datasheet?